# How to check whether cost have already been added this quarter or not

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a calendar with my company's costs for each month for planning purposes. I want to create scenarios where I can see how my finances develop if I added a new sales guy in Q3, etc. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to build my formula in Excel to check whether the cost for the quarter have already been added in the last month or not.

To give you a better idea my current formula does the following:
 1. check if the date of today is past the date of the calendar month, if so just take the cost of the previous month
 2. if it's not past the calendar month it should check what quarter it is and add the cost for that quarter to the cost of the previous month
 3. THE PROBLEM: Suppose it's May now and It already has added the cost for this quarter in April then it's supposed to copy the value of april withouth adding the quarterly cost again

Formula:

```
=IFS($AI$4="Status Quo",AI23,$AI$4=2,IF(TODAY()>AJ22,AI23,IFS(ROUNDUP(MONTH(AJ22)/3,0)=1,AI23+SUMIF($C$11:$C$37,1,$B$11:$B$37),ROUNDUP(MONTH(AJ22)/3,0)=2,AI23+SUMIF($C$11:$C$37,2,$B$11:$B$37),ROUNDUP(MONTH(AJ22)/3,0)=3,AI23+SUMIF($C$11:$C$37,3,$B$11:$B$37),ROUNDUP(MONTH(AJ22)/3,0)=4,AI23+SUMIF($C$11:$C$37,4,$B$11:$B$37))))
```

Comment: To have a better idea ourselves please edit your question and add any relevant formulas that you are working with

Comment: Ok, I've edited it to include my current formula

Comment: `IFS` inside an `IF` inside `IFS`... sweet. It's going to be hard for anyone to make heads or tails of your setup unless you include sample data with desired vs actual outcomes.